# Inserting symbols' definitions during read time of the code

Tags: evaluation, packages, contexts

Let's say we've got a package:

```
data = "
 BeginPackage[\"Test`\"]

 testFunction::usage=\"-\";

 Begin[\"`Private`\"]

 testFunction[]:= {123, explicitvalue, Hold[explicitvalue]};

 End[]
 EndPackage[]
 ";

path = FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "testPackage.m"};

Export[    path,    data,     "Text"]
```

and let's say

```
Test`explicitvalue = {1, 1, 1}
```

is defined before we read it.

New we can get it:

```
Get[path]

?? testFunction
testFunction[]
```

> testFunction[]:={123,explicitvalue,Hold[explicitvalue]}
>
> ```
> {123, {1, 1, 1}, Hold[explicitvalue]}
> ```

This is correct and expected but how to construct the behaviour mentioned in the title so that after `Get` we will have the following definition of `testFunction`:

> testFunction[]:={123,{1, 1, 1},Hold[{1, 1, 1}]}

In context of only the package we could just inject `{1, 1, 1}` value with `With[{explicitvalue = {1, 1, 1}}...`.

But that's not the case.

Is this possible without modifying the package contents?

Comment: Perhaps a [Template](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WorkingWithTemplates.html) with a `TemplateExpression` could be made to do what you require?

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar yes I was thinking about this but I suppose it will be horribly slow (relative to pure Get). I haven't tested it though, I will do this later.

Comment: The example as written defines `explicitvalue` in the private part of the package.  We need to reference it in the public part, e.g. add `explicitvalue::usage = "..."` before the private part.

Comment: @WReach I'm evaluating ``Test`explicitvalue = {1, 1, 1}`` before `Get@path`.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, but `testFunction` as written is defined to use ``Test`Private`explicitvalue`` (I'm thinking defensively).

Comment: @WReach not yet, it will find ``Test`explicitvalue`` because ``Test` `` is on context apth. The point is to inject value to multiple subpackages from parent package which gets them, like JLink does. In such case Begin/EndPackage are only in the main one but I didn't want to complicate the question.

Comment: @WReach I'm sorry I though it was kind of clear from my statement about With.

Comment: `DownValues[testFunction] = DownValues[testFunction] /. HoldPattern@explicitvalue -> explicitvalue`?

Comment: @jkuczm The point is also to not take a special care about each function. I would like to use `explicitvalue` many times in different places and in different subpackages.

Answer (score 5):

We can replace something, in all definitions associated with a symbol, using function like this:

```
ClearAll[replaceExtendedDefinition]
SetAttributes[replaceExtendedDefinition, HoldFirst]
replaceExtendedDefinition[sym_, rules_] :=
    Replace[
        Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
        ,
        (rule:Rule | RuleDelayed)[lhs_, rhs_] :>
            With[
                {eval =
                    With[
                        {heldRhs = 
                            Replace[HoldComplete[rhs], rules, {1, Infinity}]}
                        ,
                        Function[Null, rule[lhs, #], HoldAllComplete] @@ heldRhs
                    ]}
                ,
                eval /; True
            ]
        ,
        {4, 5}
    ]
```

We can easily use it for all symbols from given context:

```
Scan[
    (Language`ExtendedDefinition[#] =
        replaceExtendedDefinition[#, HoldPattern@explicitvalue -> explicitvalue])&
    ,
    Names["Test`*"]
]
```

Now we have:

```
??testFunction
(* - *)
(* testFunction[] := {123, {1, 1, 1}, Hold[{1, 1, 1}]} *)
```

`replaceExtendedDefinition` in current form replaces all occurrences of replaced expressions on right hand side of definitions including those in local scopes, which may not be desirable. Its advantage is that it can replace more complicated expressions, not only symbols.

---

Version using [Szabolcs's `With` trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88794/14303). It avoids replacements of symbols in local scopes, but does not allow replacements of more complicated expressions.

```
ClearAll[extendedDefinitionWithReplacement]
SetAttributes[extendedDefinitionWithReplacement, HoldAll]
extendedDefinitionWithReplacement[vars : {(_Set | _SetDelayed) ..}, sym_] :=
    ReplacePart[
        Unevaluated @ With[vars, Null],
        {2} -> Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ]
```

Test symbol with all possible `...Values`:

```
ClearAll[test, var]
test::usage = "test is a test symbol.";
SetAttributes[test, Listable];
Format[test] = "TEST" <> ToString[var];
test[var][var_] := var;
test[var_] := var;
test[1, var] := Module[{var}, var];
f[test] ^= var;
N[test] = var;
Default[test] = var;
test = var;
```

Its extended definition:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[test]
(* Language`DefinitionList[TESTvar -> {
    OwnValues -> HoldPattern[TESTvar] :> var,
    SubValues -> {HoldPattern[TESTvar[var][var_]] : >var},
    UpValues -> {HoldPattern[f[TESTvar]]->var},
    DownValues -> {
        HoldPattern[TESTvar[1, var]] :> Module[{var},var],
        HoldPattern[TESTvar[var_]] :> var},
    NValues -> {HoldPattern[N[TESTvar, {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}]] -> var},
    FormatValues -> {
        HoldPattern[TESTvar] :> "TEST" <> ToString[var],
        HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[TESTvar, FormatType_]] :> Format["TEST" <> ToString[var], FormatType]},
    DefaultValues -> {HoldPattern[Default[TESTvar]] -> var},
    Messages->{HoldPattern[TESTvar::usage] -> test is a test symbol.},
    Attributes->{Listable}
}] *)
```

And definition with replacement:

```
extendedDefinitionWithReplacement[{var = value}, test]
(* Language`DefinitionList[TESTvar -> {
    OwnValues -> HoldPattern[TESTvar] :> value,
    SubValues -> {HoldPattern[TESTvar[value][var_]] :> var},
    UpValues -> {HoldPattern[f[TESTvar]] -> value},
    DownValues -> {
        HoldPattern[TESTvar[1, value]] :> Module[{var}, var],
        HoldPattern[TESTvar[var_]] :> var
    },
    NValues -> {HoldPattern[N[TESTvar, {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}]] -> value},
    FormatValues -> {
        HoldPattern[TESTvar] :> "TEST" <> ToString[value],
        HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[TESTvar, FormatType$_]] :> Format["TEST" <> ToString[value], FormatType$]},
    DefaultValues -> {HoldPattern[Default[TESTvar]] -> value},
    Messages -> {HoldPattern[TESTvar::usage] -> test is a test symbol.},
    Attributes->{Listable}
}] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is messy and imperfect, but it will work in simple cases:

Import the package contents:

```
pack = ImportString[data, {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}]

(*
{HoldComplete[BeginPackage["Test`"]], 
 HoldComplete[testFunction::usage = "-";], 
 HoldComplete[Begin["`Private`"]], 
 HoldComplete[testFunction[] := {123, explicitvalue, Hold[explicitvalue]};], 
 HoldComplete[End[]], HoldComplete[EndPackage[]]}
*)
```

`Import` won't case about the `Begin` and `BeginPackage`, so the symbol we get is now `` Global`explicitvalue ``, not `` Test`explicitvalue ``.  This may cause problems if the package refers to more symbols named `explicitvalue` in multiple contexts, without using a fully qualified name.  If it doesn't (as is usually the case), we can simply replace it:

```
pack = pack /. HoldPattern[explicitvalue] -> {1, 1, 1}

(* {HoldComplete[BeginPackage["Test`"]], 
 HoldComplete[testFunction::usage = "-";], 
 HoldComplete[Begin["`Private`"]], 
 HoldComplete[testFunction[] := {123, {1, 1, 1}, Hold[{1, 1, 1}]};], 
 HoldComplete[End[]], HoldComplete[EndPackage[]]} *)
```

Now we can re-export the package into a file and load it:

```
Export[..., pack, {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}]
```

It is important to load it from a file with `Get` or `Needs` if it uses functionality such as `$InputFileName` (which only work in packages).

---

Of course one big problem is that you might not want to replace every single occurrence of `explicitvalue` to respect localization in `Module` and similar functions.

A partial solution to this is using `With` instead of `ReplaceAll`.

Compare

```
expr = Hold[Module[{a = 1}, a^2], a^2, HoldComplete[a], a::usage = "-", f[a_] := a^2]

expr /. a -> 42

(* Hold[Module[{42 = 1}, 42^2], 42^2, HoldComplete[42], 42::"usage" = "-", f[Pattern[42, _]] := 42^2] *)
```

with

```
Unevaluated@With[{a = 42}, e] /. e -> expr

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1}, a^2], 1^2, HoldComplete[1], 1::"usage" = "-", f[a_] := a^2] *)
```

The `With` avoided replacement in the `Module` and the function definition, but didn't avoid it in the message definition (which is probably a place where you'd also want to prevent it).